# sequentially distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains a time and an integer value to store time based machine usage.

Example:

```
Time    /   machine
11:00       1
12:00       2
13:00       2
14:00       1
15:00       5
16:00       5
17:00       1
```

To find machine changes I have to filter rows which are sequential and contains same machine id. now, i'm doing this by selecting all rows and searching machine changes in a while loop.

What I'm waiting is;

```
Time    /   machine
11:00       1
12:00       2
14:00       1
15:00       5
17:00       1
```

Is there a way to do it with sql or tsql? I'm currently using 2008 R2 but i'm planning to use newer versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LAG` (available from SQL Server 2012 onwards) to get the machine id of the previous record. You can then compare the id of the current record to the id of the previous record in an outer query:

```
SELECT [Time], Machine
FROM (
   SELECT [Time], Machine, LAG(Machine) OVER (ORDER BY [Time]) AS PrevMachine
   FROM MachineTable ) m
WHERE (PrevMachine IS NULL) OR (machine <> PrevMachine)
```

Please note that you also need predicate `PrevMachine IS NULL`, since there is no previous record for the first record.

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c9a4d/1)

For SQL Server 2008 the above query could be written as:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT [Time], Machine, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Time]) AS rn
FROM MachineTable
)
SELECT c1.[Time], c1.machine 
FROM CTE AS c1
LEFT JOIN CTE AS c2 ON c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
WHERE (c2.machine IS NULL) OR (c1.machine <> c2.machine)
```

Comment: i'll accept your answer but i've a question; what about the performance? which is better,using this solution(s) or using table-valued function which returs temp table.

Comment: @sddk The best thing to do in these cases is try both solutions on your actual data and see which query performs better. My guess is that my query performs better compared to a query using a correlated subquery, especially if there is a large number of records in the source table.

Comment: That is a pretty nice use of Lag +1.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablebname t1
where t1.machine <> (select top 1 machine from tablename t2
                     where t2.time < t1.time
                     order by t2.time desc)
```

If row "before" time-wise has same machine, do not return this row.

Comment: the first row or first machine always get losts [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5010/3/0)

Comment: OK. I see, NULL when sub-query row not found... Will edit later.